# Responsive Layout with CSS troubles on Clearfix

Tags: css, responsive-design, clearfix

I am creating my first real responsive layout and experiencing difficulties with css & clearfix. I made a JS fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/GFXP9/1/) demonstrating the problem with the code I created.

Basically I just want 'Line 1' and 'Line 2' to site beneath each other without a space. I plan to place quite a few divs inside the .line div's hence why I believe I need to clearfix them up.

CSS

```
div#content {max-width: 400px; min-width: 300px; margin:0 auto; }
div#left {width: 100px; background:#CCC;  float: left; }
.line {border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
div#right {background:#F63; margin-left: 100px;}

/* Clearfix */
.CF:after { content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
.CF { display:inline-block; }
/* IE mac \*/
.CF { display:block; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="content" class="CF">

<div id="left" class="CF">
    Left Content <br/>
    Displayed<br/>
    Demo<br/>
    Problem.
</div>

<div id="right" class="CF">
    <div class="CF line"> Line 1</div>
    <div class="CF line"> Line 2</div>
    <div class="CF line"> Line 3</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to avoid clearing `.CF` with :after from `#left` you need to add `overflow:hidden;` to `.CF`.

`.CF` will not need the clearfix pseudo since `overflow` will do the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/GFXP9/5/

Comment: Cheers mate. Really appreciate your input.